# Tabelas materialize

Tags: html, css

Alguém sabe como posso deixar esta tabela alinhada com o com a parte branca do fundo? Estou usando materialize.

Imagem de como ela esta.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da tabela

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
    <div class="box">
       <div class="box-content">
          <table class="bordered highlight centered">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>ID</th>
                   <th>Name</th>
                   <th>E-mail</th>
                   <th>Item Price</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                <tr>
                   <td>1</td>
                   <td>Alvin</td>
                   <td>Alvin@admin.com</td>
                   <td>$0.87</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>2</td>
                   <td>Alan</td>
                   <td>Alan@admin.com</td>
                   <td>$3.76</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>3</td>
                   <td>Jonathan</td>
                   <td>Jonathan@admin.com</td>
                   <td>$7.00</td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
          </table>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Meu css

```
.box {
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    background: #fff;
}
.box-content, .box-footer{
    padding: 15px 20px;
}
```

Comment: O materialize é responsivo. Isso deve estar ocorrendo por algum outro código no seu CSS ou HTML. Fica complicado de dar uma resposta apenas pelo código fornecido.

Comment: Olá, realmente você esta certo, dei uma atualiza no post, colocando os código do meu css. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Vc já testou na resolução de 320 pixels?

Comment: É porque o código que vc postou não aparece os botões de editar e excluir

Comment: Sim, este código que postei é de outra tabela que esta com o mesmo problema, pensei que assim assim ficaria melhor de entender sem muito código desnecessário, irei atualizar a foto ...

Comment: Incluí um CSS na resposta que pode ser útil e evitar que emails longos forcem a largura da tabela. Abs!

Comment: Assim, após analisar não encontrei erro com os códigos fornecidos porém da uma verificada se no <head> da sua página existe esse meta abaixo só por desencargo de consciência: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua tabela não tem problema algum. A menor largura em um dispositivo móvel (recentes e pré-recentes) é de `320px` de largura (ex., iPhone 3, 4) e não apresenta esse problema, a tabela consegue se encaixar tranquilamente nessa resolução mínima de 320px.

Se seu layout **não** apresenta problemas em 320px ou maior, não há com que se preocupar. Quem deve se *preocupar* é o visitante que deve atualizar o dispositivo para se adequar à modernidade.

Veja um print de um iPhone 4:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Adicional:

Pode ser que um endereço de email mais longo possa *forçar* a tabela além do limite. Para evitar isso, inclua este código no seu CSS:

```
td{
   word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: Dvd sobre o CSS no final, não seria: `td { word-wrap: break-word; }` ou então  `td { word-break: break-all; }` ? Acho que vc misturou as classes ;)

Comment: @hugocsl É mesmo, escrevi errado. Valeu!